# Change the color of a texture

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

is it possible to change a color of a texture to a random color and how can I do that if it's possible? 
I think another way is to create a sprite sheet with the object in different colors and change the region randomly, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: With `PixMap` you can get into the individual pixels to change it. Not sure what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a white texture then you can just change the spritebatch colour to tint the image.

```
batch.setColor(new Color(r,g,b,a));
batch.draw(texture, x, y);
batch.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,1)); // reset to default colour
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change color of `Texture` because that is in GPU memory. You can't directly modify their pixels whenever you want since they are on OpenGL context. You can use `Pixmap` which is a map of pixels kept in local memory with some methods to perform all modifications.

In other way you can achieve your requirement using these following ways :

1. You can use `setColor()` which is overloaded method of `Batch` Interface.

   These are the prototype of `setColor` method.

   ```
   public void setColor (Color tint); 
   public void setColor (float r, float g, float b, float a);
   public void setColor (float color);
   ```

   Set the color of the `SpriteBatch` for your texture that you want to show colored, and after you drawn put the `Spritebatch` color to white again.

OR

2. You can use `Sprite` that holds the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing 2D sprites.

   ```
   Texture myTex=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
   Sprite sprite=new Sprite(myTex);
   sprite.setColor(Color.BLUE);
   ```

Setting Random Color is just small logic, either you want to set random color at once or with some delay duration.

Comment: How can I draw a sprite on a stage? With stage.getBatch( ).draw ?

Comment: `sprite.draw(stage.getBatch())`, also keep your draw between  `begin()` and `end()`. If you're using scene2d you should use `Image` instead of `Sprite`